# How to write a bash script that will recursively counts the number of words in each document?

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu

I need to write a bash script that will recursively find all files under a directory **given as an
argument** and counts the number of words in **each** document.

The code I've tried so far is found below, but it is not working:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

echo "Script initialized."

# Putting on a variable the address given as an argument:
BaseDirectory=${1}

echo ""
echo "Full address of the base directory: $BaseDirectory"
echo ""

# Finding (recursively) all the *.txt files from the directory this script is being executed:
echo "Text files to be analyzed are the following:"
find . -iname '*.txt' -exec echo "{}" \;
echo ""

for File in $BaseDirectory
do
        echo "File name: $File"
        NumberOfWords=(wc -w $File) #Counting the words present in the file
        echo "Number of words within this file: $NumberOfWords"
        echo ""
done

echo ""
echo "Script totally executed."
echo ""

read -p "Press [ENTER] to close this window."
```

I'm using **Ubuntu terminal** to execute the script with the following command line:
**sudo bash myscript.sh /home/myuser/Documents/**

Other folder addresses I've tried include:

- /home/myuser/Documents/*
- /home/myuser/Documents/*.txt
- /*

And so on...

Where "/home/myuser/Documents/" is the full address of the directory given as an argument and its also the folder my bash script "**myscript.sh**" is located.

The output of my script is the following:

---

"Script initialized.

Full address of the base directory: /home/myuser/Documents/

Text files to be analyzed are the following:

./README.txt

./TestFiles/test.txt

./TestFiles/names.txt

File name: /home/myuser/Documents/

Number of words within this file: wc

Script totally executed."

---

I can't find whats wrong. Maybe its the directory address I'm giving as a parameter or maybe its the logic of my script. I'm pretty lost here and any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try pasting your code into http://shellcheck.net

Comment: `find . -type f -iname '*.txt'` is sufficient for your find command (the `-type f` prevents the off directory named `mydir.txt` from being included). Your `for` loop will not recurse into subdirectores, but using `while read -r fname; do .. done < <(find . -type f -iname '*.txt')` will.

Comment: Also, you need only one `printf "\nScript totally executed.\n\n"` or one `echo -e ..` rather than three `:)`

Comment: Change `(wc -w $File)` into `$(wc -w $File)` for preventing the incorrect message "Number of words within this file: wc".

Answer (score 2):

Why not a simple **find** and wc -w to count words?

```
find . -type f -exec wc -w {} \; | sort -n
```

Comment: You might consider using `-execdir wc -w '{}' +` instead, but +1 for the find solution and the numeric sort.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment to `NumberOfWords` does not execute `wc`. An assignment of the form

```
a=(foo bar baz)
```

creates a 3-element array `a` with the elements `foo`, `bar` and `baz`.

Since you already use `find`, I wonder why you aren't simply doing a

```
find $BaseDirectory -iname '*.txt' -exec wc -w {} \;
```

BTW, I would also provide a default value for the base directory, i.e.

```
BaseDirectory="${1:-.}"
```

so if the user does not supply one, the command operates on the current working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try this on the for loop section.

```
for File in "$BaseDirectory"/*.txt
do
        echo "File name: $File"
        NumberOfWords="$(wc -w < "$File")" #Counting the words present in the file
        echo "Number of words within this file: $NumberOfWords"
        echo
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the below code for your output and change the line accordingly in your code

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
echo "Script initialized."

# Putting on a variable the address given as an argument:
BaseDirectory=${1}

echo ""
echo "Full address of the base directory: $BaseDirectory"
echo ""

# Finding (recursively) all the *.txt files from the directory this     script is being executed:
echo "Text files to be analyzed are the following:"
find $BaseDirectory -iname '*.txt' -exec wc -w {} \;
echo ""

for File in $BaseDirectory
do
    echo "File name: $File"
    NumberOfWords=(wc -w $File) #Counting the words present in the file
    echo "Number of words within this file: $NumberOfWords"
    echo ""
done

echo ""
echo "Script totally executed."
echo ""

read -p "Press [ENTER] to close this window."
```

[image: Output of the script]